# emmeans - change reference level of contrast

Tags: contrasts, marginal-effect

Good day

I need some help, I used the following code:

`EMM <- emmeans(model1, ~ A | B)`

`PRS <- contrast(EMM, "pairwise")`

`summary(PRS, type = "response", infer = c(TRUE, TRUE))`

`VarCorr(model1) # to calculate sigma`

`Con <- confint(PRS, type = "response", bias.adj = TRUE, sigma = 0.65767, offset = 0)`

"A" has two levels: 0 and 1

Unfortunately, the final result of the contrast gives me the ratio for level 0 relative to level 1 but I would like the inverse. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

@Russ Lenth informed me that "revpairwise" instead of "pairwise" works, and it did, like a charm.